# How to connect and encrypt traffic between dockers runnning on different servers?

Tags: docker, security, server

I currently have six docker containers that were triggered by a docker-compose file. Now I wish to move some of them to a remote machine and enable remote communication between them.

The problem now is that I also need to add a layer of security by encrypting their traffic. 
This should be for a production website and needs to be very stable so I am unsure about which protocols/approaches could be better for this scenario.

I have used port forwarding using ssh and know that could also apply some stability through autossh. But I am unsure if there are other approaches that could help achieve the same idea by also taking into account stability and performance.

What protocols/approaches could help on this aim? How do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend manually configuring docker container connections across physical servers because docker already contains a solution for that called Docker Swarm. Follow [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/) to configure your containers to use a docker swarm. I've done it and it's very cool!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have been checking on that and it seems very interesting. I will give it a try.